# Add item into array if not already in array

Tags: python, arrays

How can I insert item into the array if its not already there?

This is what I tried:

```
    [..]
    k = []
    for item in myarray:
        if not item in k:
             print("Item is in array already.")
             k[] = item
```

Comment: I think you are using some strange syntax presumably because you think arrays are a built-in type in Python and you're carrying over syntax from some other language that you know. They're not. The built-in type for Python is called list.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your code has the right idea but just use `k.append(item)` instead of `k[] = item`.

Also it is cleaner to say `if item not in k:`

Answer (score 11):

`k[] = item` is invalid syntax. All you need to do is just remove that line and use [`list.append()`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

```
for item in myarray:
    if not item in k:
        print("Item is in array already.")
        k.append(item)
```

`list.append()` adds an item to the end of the list.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the order of the items in the list, you can convert it to a set to filter out any duplicates.

`k = list(set(myarray))`

Or if k already contains something...

```
k = [...]  # optionally non-empty array
k = list(set(k) | set(myarray))
```

What that does is convert both myarray and k into sets, and combines them so that the result is a unique list that containing the contents of both k and myarray.

Comment: re: "if you don't care about the order...", you should not be using a python `list()`.   Always use a `set()` if you don't care about order, but that's not answering the OP's question.

Comment: Also, will not work with array of unhashable types like 'dict' within array but good to know this