# New to python and I'm trying to add an item to individual lists in a nested list

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a code that will add milk to each list in a shopping cart (nested list). But if there is already milk in that list, milk should not be added to it.

```
shopping_cart= [
    ['Soap', 'Floss', 'Hand Sanitizer','Baby wipes'],
    ['Chickpeas', 'Blueberries', 'Granola'],
    ['Crayons','Construction paper','Printer ink']
    ]

if inputs== ('Calcium'):
    for i in range(len(shopping_cart)):
       shopping_list = shopping_cart[i]
       for j in range(len(shopping_list)):
           item=shopping_list[i][j]
           if item!='milk':
           item=item+'milk'
       print ('Here is your new shopping cart:\n')
       print (shopping_cart)
```

Comment: You want to change `'Soap'` to `'Soapmilk'` in the shopping cart?

Comment: `[x+['milk'] if 'milk' not in x else x for x in shopping_cart]`  Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add item into array if not already in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18796331/add-item-into-array-if-not-already-in-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need nested loops. You just need to loop over the main list, not the nested lists, so you can append to that list. You can use the `in` operator to test if a list contains something, you don't do that by looping (your loop will falsely say that the list doesn't contain `milk` when any of the elements are not `milk`).

Also, get in the habit of using `for item in list:` rather than `for index in range(len(list)):`

```
for l in shopping_cart:
    if 'milk' not in l:
        l.append('milk')
```

Comment: Note, this won't work if it needs to be case-insensitive. Should Milk be added if milk is already there.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably also want to consider capitalization.

Should Milk be added if milk is there? If not, make sure you're comparing lowercase to lowercase.

```
new_item = "milk"
for l in shopping_cart:
    l_lc = [x.lower() for x in l] # lowercase version of list
    if new_item.lower() not in l_lc:
        l.append(new_item)
```

You could also consider having a "shadow" dictionary so you're doing faster lookups and not converting the list to lowercase every time. Replace each list with a structure that has the list, as well as a dictionary of each item in lower case. May be overkill if it's a small list of lists.